# Making a button that goes to the page position of a `div` on a different tab but tabs are in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm kinda a noob on Laravel, in one of my views of my application I have some bootstrap tabs with content on them.

I have to make a button on the first tab that takes you to a specific `div` position on the last tab, can't find and example anywhere.

I've tried using some JavaScript but the button does nothing and in the chrome console says:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   6ImagenAudioVideo:98 Uncaught ReferenceError: goto is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (ImagenAudioVideo:98)

Below is my code.

The tabs:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-header">Configurarcion de plantilla imagen, audio, video</div> 

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#insEntorno">Instrucciones de entorno</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#lineaB">Linea base</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#descansos">Descansos</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fases">Fases</a></li>                                   
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content ">
       <!-- Some content -->
    </div>
    <!-- More content -->
</div>
```

After the `div` "tab-content" is the `div` where I need to go, so is the last tab is way down the html.

The simple button:

```
  <input type="button"  onclick="goto('#imgf1')"  value="Configuracion de instrucciones de entorno "/>
```

Js :

```
function goto(url) {
    window.location = url;
}
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: As I understand it, Bootstrap's tab API looks for that `href="#foo` value to identify which tabbed content it should show. A tab with `href="#foo"` shows a tab pane of with `id=foo`. I think that behavior might be overriding what you're trying to do by using an id as an anchor to a specific `<div>`. 

I'm not sure how to resolve this, except that, from a UX perspective, if the content with the anchor is important enough to merit the anchor, it's likely important enough to merit its own tab.

Comment: That could be the plan b for sure, thanks ill think about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for replying so late but here es the code that worked for me! Thanks everyone for the help :) hope someone find this useful.

Here is the javascript:

```
function goto() {
$('#tbs a[href="#fases"]').tab('show');
document.getElementById('imgf1').scrollIntoView();
```

}

And the html:

```
<ul id="tbs"class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                         <li class="nav-item"><a  class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#insEntorno">Instrucciones de entorno</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"  data-toggle="tab" href="#lineaB">Linea base</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#descansos">Descansos</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#fases">Fases</a></li>                                   
                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content ">
                         <div id="inicio" class="container tab-pane active">
                                <div id="centrarB">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="goto()"> fases </button>

                                </div>
                           </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a new tab, invoke `window.open` instead of assigning to `window.location`.  I believe that the URL will need to contain the URL to the page, even if it's the same page, plus the hashtag of the id you want to scroll to.

Also, be aware that if you do this inside Javascript code instead of using a plain anchor tab with the target attribute set to a new tab, you run the risk of running afoul of ad blockers and popup blockers stopping your app from functioning.  (Source: I just had this problem last week!)

Comment: Thanks ill try this!, im not worried of the ad blockers this is going to be a private page for use mostly for lab professors and grad students, ill let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-header">Configurarcion de plantilla imagen, audio, video</div> 

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="tablinks active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#insEntorno">Instrucciones de entorno</a></li>
            <li class="tablinks"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#lineaB">Linea base</a></li>
            <li class="tablinks"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#descansos">Descansos</a></li>
            <li class="tablinks"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fases">Fases</a></li>                                   
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content ">
           <!-- Some content -->
        </div>
        <!-- More content -->
    </div>



<input type="button"  onclick="goto('fases')"  value="Configuracion de instrucciones de entorno "/>
```

and this script

```
<script>
function goto(tabId) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(tabId).style.display = "block";
  tablinks[3].className += " active";
  document.getElementById('yourDivIdHere').scrollIntoView();
}
</script>
```

asegurate de que el indice "[3]" corresponde al tab al que quieres ir... en este caso el tab #faces es el indice 3 pero tenlo en cuenta por si deseas cambiarlo y de reemplazar "*yourDivIdHere*" por el id al que quieres hacer scroll

make sure that the index "[3]" corresponds to the tab you want to go to... in this case the tab #faces corresponds to the index 3 but keep it in mind in case you want to change it and replace "*yourDivIdHere*" with the id you want to scroll

Comment: Hola intente como me dijiste, pero cuando das click como que si te pone en la posición de la pagina donde estaría el div pero no cambia de pestaña se queda en la misma y como que se des selecciona la pestaña en la que esta. Intente cambiar el " onclick="goto('fases')" a  "onclick="goto('#fases')" pero me manda este error en la consola de chrome:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at goto (cenidet.js:11).

Comment: Hi i tried as you said but when i click the button it seems like it scrolls to the position of the page where the div should be but it doesnt change to the tab, it stays in the same tab and the active tab is not selected anymore i tried changing the  onclick="goto('fases')" to "onclick="goto('#fases')" but it sends this error on the chrome console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at goto (cenidet.js:11)

Comment: ya pudiste solucionarlo?

Comment: Yes! check my answer thank you! Si mira mi respuesta arriba gracias!